# Spring boot + jpa + scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, spring-data-jpa

```
  `package com.example;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.model.Fan;
import com.example.model.Led;
import com.example.model.Nutrient;
import com.example.model.Water;
import com.example.service.FanScheduleService;
import com.example.service.FanService;
import com.example.service.LedScheduleService;
import com.example.service.LedService;
import com.example.service.NutrientScheduleService;
import com.example.service.NutrientService;
import com.example.service.WaterScheduleService;
import com.example.service.WaterService;


@EnableScheduling
@Service
//cron = "${scheduling.job.cron}"
public class ScheduleJob {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=500,initialDelay=500)

    public void run() throws ParseException {
        LedSchedule();
        FanSchedule();
        NutrientSchedule();
        WaterSchedule();

    }
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    @Autowired
    private FanService fanService;
    @Autowired
    private FanScheduleService fanScheduleService;
    @Autowired
    private LedService ledService;
    @Autowired
    private LedScheduleService ledScheduleService;
    @Autowired
    private NutrientService nutrientService;
    @Autowired
    private NutrientScheduleService nutrientScheduleService;
    @Autowired
    private WaterService waterService;
    @Autowired
    private WaterScheduleService waterScheduleService;

    public void FanSchedule() throws ParseException{
        boolean test = true;
        Date start = null;
        Date end = null;
        Fan fan = new Fan();
        for (int i = 0; i < fanScheduleService.findAll().size(); i++) {
            String start_date = fanScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getFan_activestartdate();
            String end_date = fanScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getFan_activeenddate();
            start = dateFormat.parse(start_date);
            end = dateFormat.parse(end_date);

            fan = fanService.findById(fanScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getFan().getFan_id());
            if (start.before(new Date()) == true && end.after(new Date())==true ) {
                test = true;
            } else if( end.before(new Date())) {
                test = false;
                }
        }
        while(test==true){
            if (start.before(new Date()) == true && end.after(new Date())==true ) {
                fan.setFan_status(true);

            }else{
                fan.setFan_status(false);

            }

            try {
                fanService.update(fan);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void LedSchedule() throws ParseException{
        boolean test = true;
        Date start = null;
        Date end = null;
        Led led = new Led();
        for (int i = 0; i < ledScheduleService.findAll().size(); i++) {
            String start_date = ledScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getLed_activestartdate();
            String end_date = ledScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getLed_activeenddate();
            start = dateFormat.parse(start_date);
            end = dateFormat.parse(end_date);

            led = ledService.findById(ledScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getLed().getLed_id());
            if (start.before(new Date()) == true && end.after(new Date())==true ) {
                test = true;

            } else if( end.before(new Date())) {
                test = false;
                }
        }
        while(test==true){
            if (start.before(new Date()) == true && end.after(new Date())==true ) {
                led.setLed_status(true);

            }else{
                led.setLed_status(false);

            }

            try {
                ledService.update(led);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void NutrientSchedule() throws ParseException{
        boolean test = true;
        Date start = null;
        Date end = null;
        Nutrient nutrient = new Nutrient();
        for (int i = 0; i < nutrientScheduleService.findAll().size(); i++) {
            String start_date = nutrientScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getNutrient_activestartdate();
            String end_date = nutrientScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getNutrient_activeenddate();
            start = dateFormat.parse(start_date);
            end = dateFormat.parse(end_date);

            nutrient = nutrientService.findById(nutrientScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getNutrient().getNutrient_id());
            if (start.before(new Date()) == true && end.after(new Date())==true ) {
                test = true;
            } else if( end.before(new Date())) {
                test = false;
                }
        }
        while(test==true){
            if (start.before(new Date()) == true && end.after(new Date())==true ) {
                nutrient.setNutrient_status(true);

            }else{
                nutrient.setNutrient_status(false);

            }
            try {
                nutrientService.update(nutrient);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void WaterSchedule() throws ParseException{
        boolean test = true;
        Date start = null;
        Date end = null;
        Water water = new Water();
        for (int i = 0; i < waterScheduleService.findAll().size(); i++) {
            String start_date = waterScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getWater_activestartdate();
            String end_date = waterScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getWater_activeenddate();
            start = dateFormat.parse(start_date);
            end = dateFormat.parse(end_date);

            water = waterService.findById(waterScheduleService.findAll().get(i).getWater().getWater_id());
            if (start.before(new Date()) == true && end.after(new Date())==true ) {
                test = true;    
            } else if( end.before(new Date())) {
                test = false;
                }
        }
        while(test==true){
            if (start.before(new Date()) == true && end.after(new Date())==true ) {
                water.setWater_status(true);

            }else{
                water.setWater_status(false);

            }
            try {
                waterService.update(water);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
```

Hi Everyone. I am trying to use Spring boot and Scheduler to update something in my database. Like the below code FanSchedule() work very nice. But the other methods work not correctly. i am trying to setStatus of those to true. But sometime status of those change to false for 5s and change back to true. Please help me with this problem thanks so much.

**MORE**

```
Hibernate: update waterpump_device set temp_max=?, name=?, status=? where id=?
Hibernate: update led_device set name=?, status=?, temp_min=? where id=?
Hibernate: update nutrientpump_device set name=?, status=? where id=?
```

Only Fan is not updated by Hibernate. I think when Hibernate update it change those status to false?

Comment: have you tried adding @Transactional to run()?

Comment: @zakariaamine i already add it but it not work. Same so i removed

Answer (score 1):

The task has a timeout, if it is not executed in X seconds, the scheduler will kill the task. What you can do is call a second method with @Async and then execute your code there. Check the Spring Documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async